# Fluent Api inserindo registros indesejáveis

Tags: c#, fluent-api

Tenho as seguintes classes:

**Estado.cs**

```
public class Estado
{
    public Int32 EstadoId { get; set; }
    public Int32 CodigoEstado { get; set; }
    public String Sigla { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cidade> CidadeLista { get; set; }        

    public Estado()
    {
        CidadeLista = new List<Cidade>();
    }
}
```

**Cidade.cs**

```
public class Cidade
{
    public Int32 CidadeId { get; set; }
    public Int32 CodigoEstado { get; set; }
    public Int32 CodigoCidade { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> EnderecoLista { get; set; }

    public Cidade()
    {
        EnderecoLista = new List<Endereco>();
    }
}
```

E os seguintes mapeamentos pra tabela:

**EstadoMap.cs**

```
public class EstadoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Estado>
{
    public EstadoMap()
    {
        ToTable("ESTADO");
        HasKey(x => x.EstadoId);

        Property(x => x.EstadoId)
            .HasColumnName("ESTADO_ID")
            .HasColumnOrder(0)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(x => x.CodigoEstado)
            .HasColumnName("CODIGO_ESTADO")
            .HasColumnOrder(1)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(x => x.Sigla)
            .HasColumnName("SIGLA")
            .HasColumnOrder(2)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(2);

        Property(x => x.Nome)
            .HasColumnName("NOME")
            .HasColumnOrder(3)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(30);
    }
}
```

**CidadeMap.cs**

```
public class CidadeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cidade>
{
    public CidadeMap()
    {
        ToTable("CIDADE");
        HasKey(x => x.CidadeId);

        Property(x => x.CidadeId)
            .HasColumnName("CIDADE_ID");

        Property(x => x.Nome)
            .HasColumnName("NOME")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(60);

        Property(x => x.CodigoCidade)
            .HasColumnName("CODIGO_CIDADE")
            //.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute { IsUnique = true }))
            .IsRequired();

        Property(x => x.CodigoEstado)
            .HasColumnName("CODIGO_ESTADO")

            .IsRequired();

        //Relationships
        HasRequired(x => x.Estado)
            .WithMany(x => x.CidadeLista)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CodigoEstado);
    }
}
```

Olhei no banco e o resultado está de acordo com o esperado, sendo a coluna `codigo_estado` da tabela `Estado` referenciada na tabela `Cidade` como FK.

Para populá-las, salvei na minha máquina as páginas do IBGE com essas informações e depois alimentei as tabelas, conforme código abaixo.

**CidadeSeed**

```
public class CidadeSeed
{
    public static void Seed(TecGasContext context)
    {
        List<Estado> listaEstado = new List<Estado>()
        {
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 12, Nome = "Acre", Sigla = "AC" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 27, Nome = "Alagoas", Sigla = "AL" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 13, Nome = "Amazonas", Sigla = "AM" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 16, Nome = "Amapá", Sigla = "AP" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 29, Nome = "Bahia", Sigla = "BA" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 23, Nome = "Ceará", Sigla = "CE" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 53, Nome = "Distrito Federal", Sigla = "DF" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 32, Nome = "Espírito Santo", Sigla = "ES" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 52, Nome = "Goiás", Sigla = "GO" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 21, Nome = "Maranhão", Sigla = "MA" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 31, Nome = "Minas Gerais", Sigla = "MG" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 50, Nome = "Mato Grosso do Sul", Sigla = "MS" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 51, Nome = "Mato Grosso", Sigla = "MT" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 15, Nome = "Pará", Sigla = "PA" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 25, Nome = "Paraíba", Sigla = "PB" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 26, Nome = "Pernambuco", Sigla = "PE" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 22, Nome = "Piauí", Sigla = "PI" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 41, Nome = "Paraná", Sigla = "PR" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 33, Nome = "Rio de Janeiro", Sigla = "RJ" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 24, Nome = "Rio Grande do Norte", Sigla = "RN" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 11, Nome = "Rondônia", Sigla = "RO" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 14, Nome = "Roraima", Sigla = "RR" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 43, Nome = "Rio Grande do Sul", Sigla = "RS" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 42, Nome = "Santa Catarina", Sigla = "SC" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 28, Nome = "Sergipe", Sigla = "SE" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 35, Nome = "São Paulo", Sigla = "SP" },
            new Estado {CodigoEstado = 17, Nome = "Tocantis", Sigla = "TO" },
        };


        foreach (var estadoItem in listaEstado)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            var content = client.DownloadString(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "file:///C:/Projetos/TecGas/CidadesPorEstado/", estadoItem.Sigla, ".html"));

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(content);
            content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

            var document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(content);

            var htmlContainer =
                    document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("html/body/div[@id='conteudo']/table[@id='municipios']/tbody/tr");

            foreach (var cidadeItem in htmlContainer)
            {
                var codigoEstado = estadoItem.CodigoEstado;
                Int32 codigoCidade = Convert.ToInt32(cidadeItem.SelectSingleNode("td[@class='codigo']").InnerText);
                var nome = cidadeItem.SelectSingleNode("td[@class='nome']").InnerText;
                Cidade novaCidade = new Cidade
                {
                    CodigoEstado = codigoEstado,
                    CodigoCidade = codigoCidade,
                    Nome = nome,
                    Estado = estadoItem
                };

                try
                {
                    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                    context.Cidade.Add(novaCidade);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Projetos\TecGas\CidadesPorEstado\Erro.txt");
                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        writer.Write(String.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:", eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State));

                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            writer.Write(String.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage));
                        }
                    }
                    writer.Close();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TecGas.BackEnd.DataAccess.TecGasContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(TecGasContext context)
    {
        CidadeSeed.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Na tabela `Estado` está tudo ok, os campos inseridos são exatamente aqueles com que alimentei a tabela. Já na tabela `Cidade` a FK `codigo_estado` está sendo alimentada com a coluna `EstadoId`. Não é o que eu desejo. Gostaria que `Cidade` armazenasse como referência não o id do `estado` mas seu código. Realizando testes, parei exatamente onde o campo `codigo_estado` da tabela `Cidade` é alimentado e o valor passado é exatamente o desejado, mas depois do `SaveChanges()` quando vou olhar no banco vejo que lá encontra-se outro valor.

Podem me ajudar a encontrar o que estou fazendo errado?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste mapeamento:

```
 HasRequired(x => x.Estado)
            .WithMany(x => x.CidadeLista)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CodigoEstado);
```

Está dizendo em qual campo da tabela `Cidade` você estará gravando o id do `Estado`, pois lá lógica diz que, se é uma referência, tem que ser o Id da tabela `estado`.

Se for um campo que não seja FK então você pode preencher manualmente.

Só uma sugestão: deixa o código abaixo fora do *loop*:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
context.Cidade.AddRange(novaListaCidade);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Eu utilizaria o `AddRange`, ou ao menos deixe só o `Add` dentro do *loop* e o `SaveChanges()` fora do *loop*. Isso aumentaria o desempenho e se em algum registro do *insert* ocorrer problema daria *rollback* em tudo automaticamente.

Comment: Olá Tânia, Com a exclusão do relacionamento a inserção funcionou normalmente. Em relação as sugestões oferecidas, tens razão, é melhor colocar tudo numa lista e depois acessar o banco uma única vez. Já estou alterando o código. De qualquer forma, sabe informar se é possível usar um outro campo que não seja o Id para usar como FK? Muito Obrigado!